How can I configure an azure pipeline to always pull merge target branch before executing build validation pipeline actions?
I have feature branch validation pipeline actions which needs access to merge target branch. Hence merge target branch must be up to date on the agent before executing those actions. How can I configure the pipeline to secure that? There is documentation on how to checkout branches from other repositories but I don't find anything for this particular case.

Is this in the context of a Pull Request? If yes, take a look at git ls-remote | grep pull (from Git Bash).

@TTT Yes, it's in the context of a pull request. But I don't understand. I've looked and the repo doesn't contain the tip of the merge target branch, only an older commit. From that and the git commands performed by the agent when initiating the job I concluded that the merge target branch isn't kept up-to-date on the agent. Am I mistaken?

That's correct. Behind the scenes AzDO creates a temporary merge commit. (You can see that with the git ls-remote command, or within the merge request, choose the 3 dots menu and then "view merge commit".) The temporary merge commit is created at the time you create the PR. The temp merge commit is updated every time the tip of your source branch changes. (Either because you pushed new commits or force pushed your source branch.) You can also update it manually in the PR by clicking on the 3 dots menu, "Restart merge".

Perhaps a possible solution to your problem is to have your pipeline force that merge commit to be recreated. I'm not sure if you can use the API to do that, but that would be ideal if you could. A second (less ideal) option would be change something about your branch and then push it again (maybe amend the tip commit without a change). A third option might be to change the PR to a draft and back, or maybe abandon and revive, and perhaps those could be done with the API- but I don't know if any of those things recreate the merge commit or not.

@TTT How about having a first pipeline action which just checks out target branch, pulls, and then somehow (I don't know how) restores the head to whatever it was before  checking out the target branch?

What do you want to do with the target branch? Let's call your target branch main. If you just git fetch, then origin/main will represent your up to date target branch.

@TTT I want do do a git diff --name-only. The output of that is used to figure out which subset of tests to run (since running all tests will take > 20h).

Got it. I think there's enough here for an answer now, which I just added.

From the comments we've determined that within your pipeline you wish to compare the Pull Request's temporary merge commit with the target branch, and we can recreate that temporary merge commit to make sure it's fully up to date as of now. Let's call the source branch feature and the target branch main:
git fetch
git switch --detach origin/main
git merge origin/feature --no-ff
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD --name-only

Detailed Explanation:

git fetch: Updates all of your remote tracking branches
git switch --detach origin/main: This is the same as checking out main, but has the added advantage of not actually being on a branch, which could become stale in the future and would either need to be updated, reset, or deleted later. Since this is (probably) throwaway work just to find a diff, you don't need to be on a branch for it. If you want to be on a branch though, you could use git switch -C some-branch-name origin/main --no-track instead. Note the -C instead of -c which makes this process repeatable the next time it runs on the same build agent.
git merge origin/feature --no-ff. This creates the temporary merge commit which might be more up-to-date than the PR's current merge commit. The --no-ff is necessary to make sure feature isn't fast-forwarded in the case it's fully up to date with main.
git diff @~1 @ --name-only: (Note I used shorthand syntax here for brevity.) This is comparing the first parent of your current commit with your current commit, so you can see which files/folders have changed. Note at this moment this is also the same as git diff origin/main @ --name-only.


what happens if this is invoked repeatedly on the agent? Will "git switch --detach origin/main" create a new unique temp object of some kind each time? So we wouldn't risk multiple merges on the same object? The only con would be that the repo would grow for each pipeline execution?

@user2052153 You don't have to worry about that. This process is repeatable and each time it will use the updated commits. And whether or not you create a branch or remain detached doesn't change anything from an object point of view. The branch just also adds a tiny file with the name of the branch pointing to that object. Also that new commit you create is so tiny it's negligible, and on most agents would be garbage collected after a period of time anyway. Note that AzDO creates a merge like this for every single PR, and every update to a PR, and AzDO itself never garbage collects anything.

will not the switch followed by merge leave the working directory not matching the feature branch? Don't we need to add a step to switch back?

Why not switch to target branch (to make sure it's updated), switch back to feature brand and then do a git diff? Seems to be simpler to understand and doesn't need to perform any merge.

@user2052153 In the comments you pointed out that target was ahead of the temporary merge commit. This means that feature is not fully up to date with the latest target.  In this case the diff between target and feature will include too many changes, because it will also include changes made only on the target which aren't relevant to your PR. Also, if you just build feature, you won't be testing the same state that you'll have after the PR is completed.

@user2052153 In the case when feature is not guaranteed to be fully up to date with target, you have 2 choices- 1) Do the temporary merge like this answer and run tests against that. 2) Update your feature branch by either merging latest target into feature, or rebasing feature onto latest target. After doing that you can diff origin/master and feature to find which tests to run, and then you can run directly against feature if you prefer. The end result state will be the same as this answer.

@user2052153 Side Note: I was using origin/master and origin/main and "latest target" all to mean the same thing. After git fetch, you can reference origin/<target-branch> instead of pulling a local copy- it just saves a step since you don't actually need a local copy of the target branch for anything to use it for diffs, merging, and rebasing.

Testing this I ran into two problems:

origin/feature doesn't exist on the agent. I guess this could be fixed with pulling that branch.


@user2052153 Replace "origin" with whatever your remote name is. You can do git branch --all to print out the list of all local and remote branches. And when you do git fetch, it updates all of those remotes with the latest from the server.

All sorted now. Thanks a lot for your patient help!

There are cases where this fails because the merge yields false merge conflicts. Is that related to that the detach which makes git lose context?

@user2052153 no, that isn't related. If you have merge conflicts you will need to first update your feature branch locally, and then push it out and let the pipeline run again. You can either merge main into feature (and regular push your feature branch) or rebase feature onto main (and force push your feature branch). Also, whether the merge conflicts are "real" or in your opinion "false" also doesn't matter. If Git thinks there are conflicts, you must resolve them first.
